# Find and replace at a particular location in list using python

Tags: python, xml

this is my tag to be inserted in the file

## new_tag="newtag"

Below is the file i have in my list ( as input )

```
  <GrandFather-Tag>

      <unique-Tags>UniqueTag</unique-Tags>

      <unique-Tags>Unique-Tag</unique-Tags>

      <Grandson-Tag>

    <param-name>dsReference</param-name>

    ***THE CORRECT AREA TO INSERT THE NEW TAG.***

      </GrandSon-Tag>

  </GrandFather-tag>
```

I need to add an entry after Grand-Son tag but anywhere before grandson tag closes.

Since this is a very big xml file, i need to make sure i add entry
only after checking if Grand-Father tag is present:

if Grand-Father Tag is present,
 check for the unique tags till Grandson-Tag,
if we get to the line where Grandson-Tag starts. add an entry to the file after grandson-tag but before
grandson tag ends and before the grandfather tag ends.

Here's the logic i came up with: but it's failing:

```
for i in input_file: #List as input

    for j in start_tag_check:   #List which has grandfather tag and grandsontag

        for k in uniquetagchecks:      #List which checks if the tags are present after startcheck but before end_tag_check

            for l in end_tag_check:     #check if the start_tag is ending

               The logic to add entry after start tag and between end tag fails.
```

all these checks are necessary since the file may have multiple similar tags,
so to increase the accuracy i've added all these checks.
Can anyone help me here? to correct this logic / a workaround method 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
counter=key;
counter -=1
for c,i in enumerate(upper_half):
    if i.startswith('<') and not i.startswith('</'):
        if (i.split('>')[0].split('<')[1]):
            upper_tags.append(i.split('>')[0].split('<')[1])
            upper_tag_index.append(c)

    counter=counter -1;

upper_dict=dict(zip(upper_tag_index,upper_tags))
upper_dict_temp=upper_dict


for index,value in enumerate(upper_half):
    for (k,val) in upper_dict_temp.items():
        if '</'+val+'>' in value:
            upper_dict.pop(k)
            break;
print("Tags above key",upper_dict)
```

this worked for me :)